# Oracle ojdbc driver over Jenkins shared library

Tags: oracle, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, ojdbc

I have this Jenkins shared library which I try to use `Ojdbc`

```
//@GrabResolver(name = 'Geomajas', root = 'http://maven.geomajas.org/')
//@Grab('com.oracle.jdbc:ojdbc14:10.2.0.1.0')
@Grab('com.oracle.ojdbc:ojdbc8:19.3.0.0')

def call(Map config = [:]) {
    println("validating...")
    try {
        println("loading class")
        //step1 load the driver class
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver")

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace()
        echo "Failed for $e"
    }
}
```

and the console it keeps throwing

`Failed for java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver`

is there a way to use it in Jenkins shared library?

Answer (score 0):

Can you make sure if you are providing the Maven co-ordinates properly and pointing to central maven (root?) ?

```
<groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
 <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
 <version>19.3.0.0</version>
```